# How to calculate days between two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to calculate days between two dates by using JavaScript?

> 1. How to get only 'day' from the date.
> 2. How to get only 'month' from the date.
> 3. How to get only 'Year' from the date.
> 4. How to calculate 'year' from the 'days'

This type of questions are have Answer is below refer it

Comment: Please take this [tour]. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moment.Js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get the difference between two dates as below.

```
var start = moment("2015-13-08");
var end = moment("2015-13-08");
start.diff(end, "days")
```

for getting day, month, year you can use native javaScript.

```
var k = new Date();
k.getDate(); //gets the date
k.getMonth() + 1 ;  //gets the month index (0-11) starting from 0, so u will get 7 
                    //  for August. Added +1 to get the  month index on 1-12  scale
k.getFullYear() ; //gets the full year.

//Year from days
 var years =  days/365 ;  //days is the no of days.
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose Your Fromdate in given textbox

```
input name="datepicker" id="textboxid" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Select your fromdate" onchange=""
```

1.your selecting date stored in one variable

```
var datepick = $("#textboxid").val();
```

//your choose date like 03/06/2015

2.you want to take day,month,year separately from the datepicker means use following format

```
 var fromdate = from.slice(0, 2);
```

//  like 03

```
 var frommonth = from.slice(3, 5);
```

// like 06

```
 var fromyear = from.slice(6, 10);
```

//like 2015
3.After getting fromdate separately we move to today date calculation.

```
 var dateString = Date.now();
```

// We get date like dateString = 1439454966423

```
 var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
```

//currentTime = Thu Aug 13 2015 14:06:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}

4.current date are stored in one variable like below

```
 var to = currentTime.yyyymmdd();
```

//2015/08/13

5.you want to take day,month,year separately from the today date  means use following format

```
 var todate = to.slice(8, 10);
```

// You get like 13

```
 var tomonth = to.slice(5, 7);
```

// You get like 08

```
 var toyear = to.slice(0, 4);
```

// You get like 2015

6.oneday calculation

```
 var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

7.you getting from date like(year,month,day) wise and todate(year,month,day) for diff calculation means use following format

```
 var firstDate = new Date(fromyear, frommonth, fromdate);

var secondDate = new Date(toyear, tomonth, todate);
```

8.below script used for days calculation between firstDate and secondDate.

```
 var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
```

9.we are calculating year from the diffdays.

```
 var getyear = Math.ceil(diffDays / 365);
```

10.To return formated datetime value you can use the following method.

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function () { var yyyy =this.getFullYear().toString(); var mm = (this.getMonth() +1).toString(); 

// getMonth() is zero-based var dd =this.getDate().toString(); return yyyy + "-" +(mm[1] ? mm : "0" +mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]); // padding };
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and it's [subtract method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)